# Yii2: Mongodb query sum() always returning 0 integer

Tags: yii2, sum, mongodb-query

I am trying to find `sum` on a field in my yii2 code with database `MongoDB` and it always returns `0` for even different conditions.

I am using `yii2-mongodb-2.1.7` in `Yii 2.0.11.2` on ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried:

```
$test = new Query();
$test->from({tablename})->where({some conditions})->max({field name})
```

Comment: Your question says that you are trying to get the [sum](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#sum()-detail) but your code shows that you are using [max](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#max()-detail) is that just a typo or are you actually really using `max` on your application?  Did you check the debugger? You can find the query sent to the server there

Comment: No, I mean to say that I want to get the sum and the sum function is not working but when I try with the max function it returning the results but sum didn't.

I want this $test->from({tablename})->where({some conditions})->sum({field name})

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. The field I try to sum is string type in MongoDB so I convert all the string to integer and then try

$test = new Query();
$test->from({tablename})->where({some conditions})->sum({field name})

It works like a charm.